# Where do you declare objects in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object representing a person:

```
function Person(_name) {
    this.name = _name;

    this.start = function() {
        var that = this
        $timeout( function sayHello() {
            console.log(that.name);
            $timeout(sayHello, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Notice that is uses the angular `$timeout` service. Where should I put this so that I can declare people in my controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

    // How do I access Person so I can do this?
    $scope.p1 = Person('nick');
    $scope.p2 = Person('amy');
    $scope.p1.start();
    $scope.p2.start();
}
```

I can put the declaration in the controller body, and it works but that doesn't seen like good design. I'm pretty sure a value, or provider is specifically for this. But not sure how it would work given the dependency on $timeout.

Comment: Data sources are usually put into Services. So you could have a PersonService handling all logic related to storing/saving/searching/whatever Person objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create objects in a factory

```
 var Person = (function (params) {
    angular.extend(this, params);

    return {
        name: params.name,
    };

});

Person.create = function create(params) {
    return new Person(params);
};

myApp.factory('Person', function ($timeout) {
    return Person;
});
```

Then in your controller you can inject the factory and create Person objects.

```
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, Person) {
    $scope.person = Person.create({ name: 'Andy' });
});
```

Comment: But how do I tell angular about the $timeout dependency?

Comment: You can inject it into the factory parameter function: myApp.factory('Person', function ($timeout) { your code });

Answer (score 0):

I would make it a [Service](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/guide/dev_guide.services) that returns a constructor.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.service('Person', function($timeout) {
    // Actual person constructor defined once when
    // the service is first instantiated
    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;

        this.start = function() {
            var that = this
            $timeout( function sayHello() {
                console.log(that.name);
                $timeout(sayHello, 1000);
            }, 1000);
        }                
    }

    this.create = function (name) {
        // Return a new instance
        return new Person(name);
    };
});
```

Note that you would use `Person.create()` to make instances in this case.